# $\lim_{x\to\infty} c\ln(x) - x$

Tags: limits

$$L = \lim_{x\to\infty} c\ln(x) - x$$

Does L diverge to $-\infty$ for all positive $c$?

It seems so for very large $c$, but taking the limit as $c$ goes to infinity yields

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\ln(x) - x = \infty$$

According to wolfram alpha.

Is it wrong to set $c = x$?

Comment: Yes and yes.$\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will diverge to negative infinity for all possible $c$. When you look at multiple limits the order you apply them in is important and affect the answer so

$$\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}c\ln x-x\right)$$
is different to
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln x-x$$

Compare it with this easier to think about example students encounter in index laws:
$$\lim_{a\to0}\left(\lim_{b\to0}a^b\right)=1\neq0=\lim_{b\to0}\left(\lim_{a\to0}a^b\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

In the original limit, note that the expression being considered can be rewritten as $\log(x^ce^{-x})$. It is well known that $x^ce^{-x}$ tends to zero for any positive $c$, so the limit is $-\infty$ for any fixed positive $c$.

Answer (score 0):

People have already answered the other question. I guess we can use the standard limit

$\lim_{t \to 0} t \log(t) = 0$.

To apply to the above limit, we factorize out $x$ and get

$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\Big( c\frac{\log(x)}{x} - 1\Big)$

$ = \lim_{x \to \infty} -x (1 - c\log(x)/x)$

$ = \lim_{x\to \infty} - x (1 + c\log(1/x) \cdot (1/x)) $

$= \lim_{x \to \infty} - x = -\infty.$

since $1/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. The factor $c$ disappears with the limit $\log(1/x)\cdot (1/x)$. This confirms that the limit is $-\infty$ for all real $c$.

Of course, one can try with Taylor expansion as well.